# Can these stair glass panels be installed according with the building code?

Tags: stairs, railing

I am having a problem with the way the three glass panels that have the diagonal cut at the top will be installed, I am not sure how well they will align as the the angle of the stairs is ~44 degrees while the angle of the cut will be ~56 degrees. Considering the geometry of my stairs, if I align them, the resulting distance distance between two panels must be 5.261". The code says no more than 4" between two spindles. How do they even sell this when they will fit a particular geometry only (or a small range)
Here is how I calculated  the above
[image]

Use this calculator to check the maths
https://www.triangle-calculator.com/?what=rt&a=b%3D8+B%3D56.671&submit=Solve
the 56.671 angle was calculated based on the panel drawing for a triangle of 152x127x83.516

Here is my design
[image]

**Here is [the product](https://www.rona.ca/en/product/colonial-elegance-verona-glass-balustrade-panel-40-angle-stair-section-39-3-8-in-l-x-6-in-w-x-3-8-in-t-gc60032-08856116) I am planning to use**

Here are the specs
[image]

Comment: How can you have a handrail with a different slope than the stairs?  It will be higher at the top than the bottom.  Pretty sure they intend you to build the stairs to match their producr

Answer (score -3, accepted):

While my other answer works to install the above if the calculated distance between two panels would be 5", in fact the real distance between two panels was calculated wrong, the 8" distance is actually between the highest point of two consecutive panels

Here is what what the numbers look like. The manufacturer did not take a blind risk. Within a couple of degrees of angle difference between the stairs and the rail that will sit on top of the below glass panels you have a large numbers of stair geometries (sizes) that will be covered. Of course there will always be a few fanatics who are able to determine a 0.005 degrees of angle differences between stairs and handrail and they will crucify you and burn you alive because it is not "code"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Planning to use a product that won't pass code is poor planning, so you can't use that product as planned. Plan to get a different product.

- Either add 1.262" of trim

or

- Buy a different sized product that works with your stairs without
  trim.

As drawn, the lack of a handrail will also fail, in my jurisdiction.

Comment: the rail will be installed but it was not represented for more clarity. I am not planning to install it I am checking if I can install it and I am asking if my assumption is correct, or there is a trick to install them (you can chose not to align the top endges)

Comment: Can you be more clear on adding the trim ? Where does that get added ? There is no trim of 1.26" that can cover the 5.6" distance between two pannels

Comment: You don't need to cover the 5.6 inches. You need to **reduce** the 5.6 inches to less than 4 inches. Trim on the edge of the glass (or separate spindles **between** the glass panels) could make the gap less than 4".

Comment: yes I realized that when I posted my answer (adding the spindles). To me that ruins the design

Comment: Then buy wider glass panels.

Comment: I wish I could find them premade. Any "custom" made solution will increase the cost ("oh it is custom it will cost you an arm and a leg"  I emailed the guys who sold me the panels for the shower ...they did not even bother to reply