# How can I cut 10mm tempered glass?

Tags: glass, cutting

I am installing [these](https://www.rona.ca/en/product/colonial-elegance-verona-glass-balustrade-panel-40-angle-stair-section-39-3-8-in-l-x-6-in-w-x-3-8-in-t-gc60032-08856116?viewStore=55140&cq_src=google_ads&cq_cmp=19745635341&cq_con=&cq_term=&cq_med=pla&cq_plac=&cq_net=x&cq_pos=&cq_plt=gp&&cm_mmc=paid_search-_-google-_-aw_pmax_generic_All%20Products-_-&gclid=Cj0KCQjwgNanBhDUARIsAAeIcAs8xDZqISfvdMSzRG3alFzgZfp2RFgoCv-KkKhdUOk3pFPOewtgHfEaAqcLEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) glass panels on my stairs.
Although I have a solution to install them in such a way that the top edges will line up, the glass panels will not sit properly centered on the treads.

I just realized that one way to fix this is to shorten one of them by cutting the bottom edge and after that polishing it a little to look almost perfect.

These are 10mm thick glass panels
I have a wet saw and I also have a [Professional Carbide Tungsten Alloy Handle Glass Cutter Tool with Range 2-19mm Professional Cutter for Thick Glass Mosaic and Tiles - Pencil Shape & Design (Glass Cutter) (Regular)](https://www.amazon.ca/Bloomoak-Professional-Carbide-Tungsten-Self-Oiling/dp/B075W8WZYY)

Comment: Maybe a pro glass person will weigh in, but I'm pretty sure tempered glass doesn't cut. I've seen my guy sand a **tiny** bit off a panel, but he's been at it all his life.

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90131/how-can-i-drill-a-hole-in-tempered-glass-without-shattering-it?rq=1

Comment: I'd bring he piece to a local glazier, explain what you need done, ald let them tell you whether they can modify it or if they'd need to cut a piece to size first and then remove it (which they can probably do or have done).

Comment: *Why* won't the panels work for you as-is?

Comment: see this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257253/can-these-stair-glass-panels-be-installed-according-with-the-building-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on some web-searching it is not possible to cut tempered glass directly. The glass must be annealed first, which reduces or removes the tempering, Then the glass can be cut in the normal ways. The glass can then be re-tempered.

Glass can also be sanded with a special sanding belt and a belt sander: we did that once in my old job in a cabinet shop. But I fail to remember if the glass was tempered.

You may have to take this glass to a glass company, where they can either anneal-resize-temper it again, or cut you a new piece to the size you need.

Another possibility, presented without seeing the stairs you're mounting to: Since the end of the glass is angled, you could mount it slightly off center from where you planned it, then it might fit. Or cut a slot in the rail or tread to countersink the mounting brackets, thus making up the length required for the glass.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense technically but I am seeing these videos, hence the question https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cutting+shower+dood+glass

Comment: Um, like this video? https://youtube.com/shorts/ncdiSXBz_FM?si=e3DCTXnwaP_qpWnN

Comment: yeap but I would hit the glass from below to propagate the crack first and I would hold the pliers such that the grip is parallel with the edge you cut ....but hey it makes sense if one plane went down due to a pilot error we should deem all the flights unsafe.

Comment: Let us know how it works, Cap'n.

Comment: Tempered glass cannot be cut. The video posted by @AloysiusDefenestrate illustrates what will happen 100% of the time if you attempt to cut tempered glass. ... However, is it certain that the panels in question are tempered? I don't immediately see that in the listing. If they are tempered, there should be a clear marking/etching on each panel saying so. If that's not present, they are most likely not tempered.

Comment: @ MiniMe, you have been asking about this glass for a month. When you do get an answer you would rather argue with the advice rather than take it. Why are you asking questions here if you prefer to reject  any answers.

Comment: @MiniMe, the video search link you posted only had one guy claim to have cut tempered glass, and did not show the actual cut. The others show what is expected to happen when tempered glass is cut, such as Aloysius Defenestrate's posted link. Tempered glass does not break across one crack. It breaks across millions of them.

Comment: The manufacturer install video says "tem.pered"  but I will doublecheck